# If $g$ is differentiable and $g(1/n)=0$ for all $n$, then $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Suppose that $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ differentiable at $x=0$ and for each natural number $n$, $g(1/n)=0$. Prove that $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=0$

---

Since $g$ is differentiable at $x=0$, so $g$ is continuous at $x=0$ and gives $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}g(x)-g(0)=0$. As for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $g(1/n)=0=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}g(x)-g(0)$. I stuck at this step, I don't see any information that I can use to get further. Can someone give me a hit or suggestion to keep going? Thanks

Comment: To prove that $g'(0)=0$, look at $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(0+h)-g(0)}{h}$.

Comment: [tag:proof-writing] is for questions about  presenting a proof that you have in mind. If you  don't have a proof, don't use proof- tags.

Comment: That is sort of answered in your [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1515508/if-x-0-is-a-limit-point-of-d-then-a-function-fd-rightarrow-mathbbr-is), $\lim_{x\to x_0} G(x) = C$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to \infty} G(x_n) = C$ for all sequences $x_n \to x_0$.

Comment: @JohnMa I am struggling to show $g'(0)=0$, not $g(0)=0$

Comment: That's the same. In this situation $G(x) = \frac{g(x) - g(0)}{x}$.

Comment: @JohnMa But I would get $g(0)/0$, I am not sure that  I can use $1/n$

Comment: When taking limit, you do not care about $x=0$ case, we care only those $x$ closed to $0$. Note also that $\frac 1n \to 0$.

Comment: @JohnMa $\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}=\frac{g(1/n)-g(0)}{1/n-0}$?

Comment: Yes, and the right hand side is always $0$. So taking $n \to \infty$ and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

since $g$ is differentiable at $x=0$, thus it is continous at $0$ thus $$g(0)=g(\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n})=\lim_{n\to \infty} g(\frac{1}{n})=0$$

Comment: There is another thing to prove.

Comment: I wanted to write, but I saw André Nicolas has hinted him.